# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in XIB

Tags: iphone, ios

In my storyboard, I am trying to link a tableview cell to a PeoplePickerNavigationController.  In the storyboard, I drag in a new view controller.  Then in the controller's Identity Inspector, I choose ABPeoplePickerNavigationController as the class.  I also create a seque by dragging from the tableview cell to the new people picker view controller.

When I run the application, the new controller is displayed, but it is blank.  What can I do to show the people picker in the new view controller?

Thanks in advance for your help.